# Creating an xml from an xmlObject

Tags: java, xml, xmlbeans

I am not able to find a suitable way to write an org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject instance to an xml file. 
Is there any api in java that can be used to write an XMLObject  like Transformer for DOCSource. I am not able to find one.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a way out , Since xmlObject is nothing but an implementation of XMLTokenSource so, we can use xmlObject.save(File) to write this object.

Comment: Close the question then, or remove it:)

Comment: someone else may find this helpfull.

Comment: But it still remains as an open question.